# What is the opposite of "Member"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns, interpersonal-relations

The relation between a user and a group is:

> The user is a **member** of the group.

What is the converse relation?

> The group is a ___ of the user.

What word suits here? Does team or union work?

Comment: 'Community' could be used, but you'd then need say 'The group is a community shared in by the user'. This is probably a lexical gap in English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'Community' looks good enough for my needs. Let me see if somebody has better words.

Comment: It might help if you explain the connotation: is this a technical term for a computer operating system where a user is assigned to a group, or is the group an actual, real-world association of people?

Comment: @StuartF I was asking in the context of a chat application, where users together can create groups. So I think, it is more closer to 'real-world association of people'.

Comment: I am sorry, but without more info it is quite difficult to answer this question.

Comment: The opposite of _member_ is _non-member_. For every group, the population divides into those two classes.

Comment: @JohnLawler "The group is a non-member of the user" does not make sense.

Comment: Neither does _The group is a member of the user_.

Comment: *Association* actually works.

Comment: Maybe *the collective*.

Comment: @JohnLawler if you see the question, 'non-member' is absolutely not the word I was looking for :(

Comment: @jxh 'association' is a good word. I will see about it.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty 'collective' is a pretty nice word.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine It's okay, I got some good answers in comment section itself :)

Comment: The group is a **set** of users.  In your first sentence, the focus is on belonging to a set.  I believe you would like to consider the flip side of this -- encompassing.  Voting to reopen because I think that as awkward as the question is, I do understand what OP is looking for.

Comment: @aparente001 'set' looks good fit for that sentence. But I was looking for a more natural word that describes a real-world relationship.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB - I like the language of mathematics and for me, "set" is a natural word which describes real-world relationships.  But there are synonyms to consider, e.g. *collection*.